# declare a control array visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

How to declare a control array in Visual Basic 6?

I am getting an error `control array element x does not exist` (which means array index out of bounds).

If I know how to declare a control array then its easy to find why I am getting the error. Are control arrays in Visual Basic 6 a dynamic array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it purely in code.

To add a control array of buttons add a `CommandButton` to the form as normal, name it `Test` and change its `index` property to 0.

This gives you a control array containing `Test(0)`, to add to the array at runtime use `Load`:

```
Dim i As Long
i = Test.UBound + 1
Load Test(i)

With Test(i)
    .Move 10, 10, 500, 500
    .Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: You may also find it interesting, that you can choose the new control's  index freely from positive integers up to 32767. You can access the controls also in a For Each loop. As Alex has hinted, loaded controls are invisible by default, and behind the template (the one you placed onto the form). Use Visible and move them to another position or use ZOrder to make them visible.